# Facebook SDK 3.6 Open Graph Error Message

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

Im trying to use the new Share Dialog and it works fine when the facebook app is not installed and im sharing with my own viewcontroller:

```
if (!call) {
        // Fallback to customized share UI
        MyShareViewController *viewController = [[MyShareViewController alloc] initWithItem:object
                                                                                 objectType:@"objecttype"
                                                                                 actionType:@"namespace:action"];
        [_delegate showFallbackShareDialog:viewController];

    }
```

So this code only gets called when the facebook app isnt installed. When it is installed the device opens the facebook app and here the user can type a message which will be included in the open graph action

[image]

But after a few second my devices switches back to my app and this error shows up:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 102.)" UserInfo=xxxx {error_code=102, action_id=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx, error_message=Could not generate preview text, app_id=xxxxx}
```

I've been searching the web for an explanation but just can't find whats wrong. Does somebody know what this error means?

**EDIT** notice the greyed out "Post" button.

Comment: have you got any solution on this? i am also facing same issue with my code.

Comment: Not yet. Is 3.6 still in beta? It isn't right?

Comment: I recently had FB issues because my app was in sandbox mode in FB settings.

Comment: Please, check my answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18981505/2811011.
This solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check following

1. **FacebookDisplayName** is set properly and correct in plist's URL Scheme
2. **fbxxxxxxxxxxx** is added in your plist file
3. **FacebookAppID** is set correctly in plist file
4. in **Status & Review** section Make sure you have **"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"** make as YES (By default it's No)