# com.facebook.sdk error 7 when trying to post og action

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Yesterday I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971713/facebook-sdk-3-6-open-graph-error-message) problem but today I couldn't even reach the facebook app for posting my og action. When I click the share button my app logs a different error and doesn't switch to the facebook app. It works fine in the simulator because it doesn't have the facebook app installed and my app shows my custom share dialog.

This is the new error:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 7.)" UserInfo=0x226bb150 {com.facebook.sdk:DialogReasonKey=DialogInvalidOpenGraphObject}
```

Does anybody know why this problem occurs? I haven't changed any code but the result is different.

Im using the new Facebook SDK 3.6